# update statement inside Trigger not updating all the rows in SQL server 2008

Tags: sql-server

I have two table.table 1 have the update trigge it will update the detail in table. but table have many rows with same key in table1.(key in table1 is primarykey but in table 2 it is foriegn key). Update trigger updating only one row in The table2 not updating the all row having same key.

```
Update  table2 set colu1 = "value" where  colu2 = primarykey
```

Comment: Please supply your trigger code. Most likely you have to join the _inserted_ virtual table to accomplish what you need.

Comment: probably you are populating variables instead of joining to the virtual table.  It's a very common mistake.  Edit your post with your trigger code.

Comment: create trigger on table1 after update as begin if update(col in table1) begin Update table2 set colu1 = "value" where colu2 = primarykey END END

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing much about your tables I think you want something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Table1Trigger ON table1
AFTER UPDATE AS
IF UPDATE(col) 
BEGIN
    UPDATE table2
    SET colu1 = 'value'
    FROM table2 
    INNER JOIN inserted ON table2.colu2 = inserted.[key]
END
```

This will change the value of `colu1` in `table2` to 'Value' for all rows that has a key value that corresponds to the key value of the rows that were updated in `table1` if the update change column `col`. You probably have to change the column names to match whatever your table looks like.